# How to upload ebooks on dtabaseses

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I recently started creating a website with angular and Django. This is to be an online bookstore or an ELibraby something like Amazon Kindle, my problem is that I found out that it's not advisable to store ebooks on a database but I need a way for users to get these ebooks from the database and for admins to be able to upload to some sort of file system since database is not possible, please is there anyway I can accomplish this on my site.

I have checked the internet but I haven't seen anything helpful, maybe I am searching wrong or something but I will really appreciate any advice.

And also I will like to know if there is any API that can help me add books to my website at least to fill in some space till actual ebooks are uploaded.

Any advise will really help...

Answer (score 0):

First, you will never want to store binary data of any sorts in the database. You will use a storage and the database will refer to that storage instead. I think you need to see how you can archive that first and then proceed with the rest.

Check Amazon S3 and https://pypi.org/project/django-storages/